# Clean up nested RxJS observable subscriptions

Tags: javascript, rxjs, observable

### Question:

In my Angular 2 app, there are a few layers of nested subscriptions for REST API calls that return observables. What's the best way to remove the nesting?

### Background:

I need to calculate the similarity between a job's skills and the user's skills for all jobs. Then I need to save that similarity percentage to the corresponding match document. There's a one-to-many relationship between users and matches. Also, there's a one-to-many relationship between jobs and matches. To update the match I need to find the ID first.

### Code:

```
// Makes a GET request to '/api/jobs'
this.jobService.getJobs().subscribe((jobs: Job[]) => {
  for (let job of jobs) {

    // Determine the similarity between a job's skills and the user's skills
    let percentage = this.calculatePercentage(job.skills, this.currentUser.skills)

    // Makes a GET request to '/api/matches/?jobId=12345&userId=11111'
    this.matchService.getMatchForUserAndJob(job._id, this.currentUser._id).subscribe((match: Match) => {

      // Makes a PATCH request to '/api/matches/54321'
      this.matchService.updateMatchPercentage(match._id, percentage).subscribe()
    })
  }
})
```

### Example schemas:

**Job**

```
{
    '_id': 12345,
    'skills': [
        { 'name': 'Skill 1' },
        { 'name': 'Skill 2' }
    ]
}
```

**Match**

```
{
    '_id': 54321,
    'jobId': 12345,
    'userId': 11111,
    'percentage': 100
}
```

### Further questions:

Is flatMap something that could work in this case?

Is there a better way to update the matches?

Comment: flatmap or switch map either can work in this case

Comment: I never used this but I came across `forkjoin` when I was researching similar problem. This might work for you. Not too sure about it.